# Silverlight: Simulate RadioButton Click event using UI Automation?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, ui-automation

In Silverlight, both the [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and the [`RadioButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) controls have a [`Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event, since they inherit from [`System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

If we want to simulate this `Click` event for a `Button`, we can use the [`ButtonAutomationPeer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.buttonautomationpeer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class, like so (given a button called `myButton`):

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(myButton);
IInvokeProvider ip = (IInvokeProvider)peer;
ip.Invoke();
```

However, when we try to do the same thing for a `RadioButton`, we discover that the [`RadioButtonAutomationPeer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.radiobuttonautomationpeer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class does not implement `IInvokeProvider` (so we can't call `Invoke()`). Is there some other way we can cause the `Click` event for a `RadioButton` to be fired?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RadioButtonAutomationPeer peer = new RadioButtonAutomationPeer(myRadioButton);
IToggleProvider tp = (IToggleProvider) peer;
while (tp.ToggleState != targetToggleState)
{
   tp.Toggle();
}
```

You'll need to know your desired toggle state (On, Off, or Indeterminate).  Or if you just want to toggle to a different state, strike the while loop just call Toggle.

Obviously this isn't the exact same thing as a click.  If you've bound the radio button to a command, you might be forced to be a little more explicit and do something like this to get your automation to work:

```
<RadioButton ... (don't set the Command property)>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</RadioButton>
```

Using the Blend SDK (that's the "i:" xmlns), you're invoking a command when the RadioButton is checked.  Personally I'd do that approach even without automation over just binding a command to a RadioButton: it's not clear when the command executes with a binding, but the triggers add some clarity and remove the need for me to think the next time I look at the code.